# momentjs won't add minutes

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date and a time value in the following formats "12-may-2014" and "16:05" respectively

I am trying to convert these two values to a moment object like so

```
var time = moment(originalDate + ', ' + orignalTime);
```

this seems to return a moment object so I do this

```
var newTime = moment(time).add('h', 3);
console.log(newTime);
```

this logs the expected time "19:05"

but if I do this

```
var newTime = moment(time).add('m', 30);
console.log(newTime);
```

instead of getting "16.30" i just get the original time "16.05"

edit: the selected answer solves my problem however if I replace

```
console.log(newTime.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"));
```

with

```
console.log(newTime.format("HH:MM"));
```

I get the original problem.  adding hours shows the correct result but adding minutes shows the original time

```
console.log(newTime.format("hh:mm"));
```

works as intended

Comment: If you were to change .add('m', 30) to .add('minutes', 30). Does it work?

Comment: No I get the same result

Comment: Might be confusing the two time variables as the answer below questions as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me.  Are you sure you aren't confusing the 2 `time` variables?

Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SsFCs4?p=preview).

**JS:**

```
var timevalue = "16:05";
var datevalue = "12-may-2014";
var time = moment(datevalue + ', ' + timevalue);

var newTime = moment(time).add('m', 30);
console.log(newTime.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"));
```

Comment: hmm so it does, now I am thoroughly confused

Comment: Are you sure the 2 `time` variables are not confused?  You are defining `time` as a `moment` and as the string `"16:05"`.

Comment: Yeah sorry that part is badly worded in my question.  they are not confused in my code.  I'll edit

Comment: I have reformatted my code to look exactly like yours but with dynamic values for timevalue and datevalue and it appears to be working. I have updated the question with what the only difference is

Answer (score 1):

For theirs, who can't understand what happening with moment.js objects

When you call `momentValue.add('minute', amount)` function it is return `Moment` object back, **but it is not clone** it is the same reference object with changed value. (between 3 and 7 lines)

So, if you don't want change original object you should use `.clone` function before apply changes. (between 9 and 14 lines)

[image: moment using clone]